# Meaning of "jump his way"

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

What does *jump his way* in the following phrase mean?

**Who watched "Fearless Felix" jump his way into the record books?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Fearless Felix" ([Felix Baumgartner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Baumgartner)) is a Skydiver/Base Jumper who holds the world record for skydiving an estimated 39 kilometres.

When they say he "*jump[ed] his way into the record books*" they are making a reference to the act for which he holds his world record (for the furthest skydiving jump).

This would be equivalent to saying that [Takeru Kobayashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takeru_Kobayashi) (who held the record for hot dog eating contests) *ate* his way into the record books (or endless other equivalent examples).

Comment: Thanks a lot, batpigandme !!! What about "danced his way out of the prison"?

Comment: Actually, Joey Chestnut holds the hot dog eating record: 69 in 10 minutes. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez whoops! Guess I'm dated in my hot dog eating contest knowledge (I still like to do the Kobayashi shake)!

Comment: @joan that might be better solved as a separate question...